# How to reach LAN website by domain name?

Tags: dns

I have a PC, router and smartphone. PC has a website, that can work only by domain name. I need to reach website with smartphone, when it is on the same network.

I've started a DNS server on PC (before it worked through hosts). It work locally if I set static IP as primary dns server of machine. Also I tried flushdns,and found that website is accessible from other device with set hosts. But looks like devices do not load DNS records, although I get many requests to DNS server in logs.

I thought that if I set the DNS IP (PC IP) into routers Primary DNS, other devices that has router as Default Gateway will load DNS records from it, but for now it is not working like that.

Help please, with advice how to solve it or with tools on how to debug.

Comment: What's the need for a DNS server? Why don't you just put an entry in the hosts file?

Comment: I dont want to root device, so I cannot change hosts

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that if I set the DNS IP (PC IP) into routers Primary DNS, other devices that has router as Default Gateway will load DNS records from it, but for now it is not working like that.

This is why you struggled.  You thought something that's not accurate.

If your check your PC, you'll find that there are separate settings for the DNS servers, and the default gateway.  They are two very different things.  (Some people might think these things are kind of related, because they seem related to a person's mind, because people learn about these terms "DNS servers" and "default gateway" at about the same time.  They simply learn that the terms are related to the common "Internet settings" that need to be set up for a device to work.)  In many cases, the IP address used for the DNS servers can be the same IP address used for the "default gateway", but that does not necessarily need to be the case.  The reason that those addresses can sometimes be the same is because computers can multitask: a single computer at one IP address can run multiple programs, including providing the "DNS server" functionality and the "default gateway" functionality.

DNS servers provide a feature called "name resolution", which is commonly used to change a name like www.example.com to an address like the IPv6 address 2001:db8::a001 and the IPv4 address 192.0.2.100

The "default gateway" is used to control "routing".  More specifically, when networking is a bit more advanced, a "gateway" refers to one way that some traffic can get routed.  The "default gateway" is the "gateway" that is used whenever a device (including a computer) does not have a more specific gateway to use.

I agree that web servers will often check for the DNS name that the web browser provides, so you may need to have DNS point to your local web server.  Your best solution is probably to change the settings on your phone, specifying which DNS server to use.  The settings on your phone might specify that the DNS server to use is whatever IP address gets provided by what I call an "automatic addressing server", such as an "IPv4 DHCP server".  If you don't see an easy way to customize the "DNS server" settings on your phone, your best bet may be to have a local "DHCP server" provide your phone with the desired "DNS server" settings.

Realize that having multiple DHCP servers on a network can cause a conflict, and may result in a "race condition" where sometimes devices get desired information, and sometimes devices get information from another server.  So, make sure that problem doesn't exist.  The most common easy approach is to just make sure you don't run more than one DHCP server on the network.  If you have a DHCP server (which might be software running on the "device" which is your router, which may be your current "default gateway") then either change the configuration of that DHCP server, or completely disable that DHCP server and run a different one.